# How to select rows with no match between two tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables t1 and t2

```
t1

plant  country    cost
------------------------
apple  usa        1
apple  uk         1
potato sudan      3
potato india      3
potato china      3
apple  usa        2
apple  uk         2


t2

country
--------
usa
uk
egypt
sudan
india
china
```

I need to return a table for countries that do not exist in t1 like so:

```
plant  country    cost
------------------------
apple  egypt      1
apple  sudan      1
apple  india      1
apple  china      1
apple  egypt      2
apple  sudan      2
apple  india      2
apple  china      2
potato usa        3
potato uk         3
potato egypt      3
```

This seems so easy but I cannot solve it.  I tried:

```
select t1.plant, t2.country, t1.cost
from t1
right outer join t1 on t1.country = t2.country
where t2 is null
group by t1.plant, t2.country, t1.cost
```

I looked at several 'not exist' questions in stack overflow but the responses did not work because there were more columns in common between t1 and t2 than in my example.  Could someone kindly point me in the right direction or show me a link to a similar problem?

Comment: Do you have a list of all possible plants? And if no row exists in table1 then where would the cost come from?

Comment: Your output expectations don't make sense. Where does cost come from if there is no match? How do `apple` and `egypt` get paired in the first row, and where do you magically pull a cost of `1` from for that pairing?

Comment: The costs and plants come strictly from t1. All apples cost 1 and all oranges cost 2.  The other option would be a cursor but i would like to avoid that.  I thought this would be easy but i am stumped

Comment: But you are saying you want to find records missing from table1 but at the same time all the data is in table1? How do you know how many different plants there are? One would normally have a table3 with a list of plants (like your list of countries).

Comment: exactly 2 plants and exactly 2 costs.  you are right, but that is the difficulty with this question

Comment: I made a mistake so I updated my question, apples have two costs 1 and 2 and potatoes only have one cost which is 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try handling this via the use of an on-the-fly calendar table:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.plant, t2.country, t1.cost
    FROM t1
    CROSS JOIN t2
)

SELECT
    a.plant,
    a.country,
    a.cost
FROM cte a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t1 b
                  WHERE a.plant = b.plant AND
                        a.country = b.country AND
                        a.cost = b.cost);
```

### Demo

Comment: This works exactly the way I reformatted my question (with multiple costs for apples)! Thank you for your help.  I feel good that this question was not so simple after all.  I hope other readers will find this useful too.

Comment: As the above comments mention, when you need to resort to using a calendar table to generate data, it often implies that your database should already have this data.  So, feel free to use my answer, but you might want to maintain separate tables for all plants, countries, and costs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `CROSS JOIN` to generate all possible combinations of `plants` and `countires`, then a `NOT EXISTS` condition with a correlated subquery to filter out those that exists in `t2`:

```
select plants.plant, countries.country, plants.cost
from t2 countries
cross join (distinct plant, max(cost) cost from t1 group by plant) plants
where not exists (
    select 1 from t1 where t1.country = countries.country
)
```

Comment: This seems to be working however, I just updated my question because your response made me realize a mistake i made in my question (thank you). how can your code be adjusted to account for the different prices for apples?

Comment: thank you for your help, your answer helped me realize my mistake.  how do i award you and tom biegeleisen with points?  I spent hours and hours on this thing.

Comment: i clicked the up button six times it said it recorded but not display the votes.  thank you again

Comment: @ithoughtso: no worries ! you need a reputation of at least 15 to upvote... You will eventually get them!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.plant, t2.country, t.cost
FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT plant , cost
FROM t1)t
CROSS JOIN t2
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.plant = t.plant and t1.country = t2.country AND t.cost = t1.cost
WHERE t1.plant IS NULL AND t1.country IS NULL AND t1.cost is NULL
```

Comment: In order to maximize the usefulness of this answer, please add a description of your code so we know what it does and why.